# delegateToSchema is not using my executor

Tags: javascript, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I want to delegate a field from my graphql service to a remote service. I tried to follow the docs, but I'm missing something.

```
const {wrapSchema, introspectSchema} = require('@graphql-tools/wrap');
const got = require('got');
const {print} = require('graphql');
const {delegateToSchema} = require('graphql-tools');

const executor = async ({document, variables}) => {
  const query = typeof document === 'string' ? document : print(document);
  return got.post('http://localhost:6677/graphql', {json: {query, variables}).json();
};

const makeRemoteSchema = async () => {
  return wrapSchema({
    schema: await introspectSchema(executor),
    executor
  });
};

const conversations = async ({id}, _, context, info) => {
  const result = await delegateToSchema({
    schema: await makeRemoteSchema(),
    operation: 'query',
    fieldName: 'conversations',
    args: {
      consultationParticipantId: id,
    },
    context,
    info
  });
  return result;
};
```

The result is `null`. I can see that it's using my executor to make the introspection call, by when resolving the field it's using the default executor instead, which is basically a no-op. By stepping through the `delegateToSchema` code it seems like it wants `schema` to be a `schemaConfig`. So I tried removing `wrapSchema` like so:

```
const makeRemoteSchema = async () => {
  return {
    schema: await introspectSchema(executor),
    executor
  };
}
```

It uses my executor and not the default, but now in the executor, `query` is resolved as empty string an `variables` is an empty object.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using:

```
"graphql-tools": "^7.0.4",
"@graphql-tools/wrap": "^7.0.8",
```

I also tried v6.2.4.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I'm running into a similar problem.